# I can not add form different element based on selectbox selection

Tags: javascript, if-statement, drop-down-menu, textbox, append

I would like to add a TextBox or SelectBox based on the selection from a selectBox whose name is rim. But it always adds a text box. Where am I making mistakes.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rim").change(function() { 
      if ($("#rim option[value='JANT']").attr("selected", "selected")) {
       $("#formal").append("<input name='opno' type='text' size='4'  placeholder='Jant Adet'/>");
      }
     else {
       $("#formal").append("<select name='opno'><option value=''>Seç</option></select>");
      }
    }); 
  });

  <div id="formal"></div>
```

Comment: `.attr("selected", "selected")` **sets** the `selected` attribute ... `.attr("selected")` will **get** the selected attribute

Answer (score 1):

In your if condition you have used `attr` which doesn't give Boolean value. So use this

```
$(this).val() === "JANT"
```

Complete Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rim").change(function() { 
      if ($(this).val() === "JANT") {
       $("#formal").append("<input name='opno' type='text' size='4'  placeholder='Jant Adet'/>");
      }
     else {
       $("#formal").append("<select name='opno'><option value=''>Seç</option></select>");
      }
    }); 
  });
```

[**Example DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/unp4rwuv/)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This worked... How to remove the other when one is added. So let's just be a form element in the elections ... <div id = "formal"> </ div>

Comment: @TamerAtasoy if you want to remove previous when new element is adding in `#formal` then just use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. Where `.html()` just replace complete HTML and `.append()` just add into content. See https://jsfiddle.net/46cv81g0/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. God bless you Manwal.